# Broken button layout on the showcase

Tags: codenameone

We are evaluating CodenameOne to adopt it as our platform.

In the Showcase App, the menu buttons layout gets broken (button smaller than the image) after changing to some Themes like the "Leather".

Tested on Samsung A5.

Is it an application or platform problem? And can you fix it?

Problem screenshot:

[image]

(not enough reputation yet to post images)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The leather theme is a legacy from circa 2014. We don't maintain it because it's gone out of vogue with current flat design styling. We haven't updated the kitchen sink either for 3 years too, since we're more focused on apps such as build.

2014 predated iOS 7 which changed a lot of details about the treatment of the status bar. That means the theme needs to be updated but because it's so full of images it's a bit of a pain. We chose to leave it there with the quirks since it shows off the versatility rather nicely although it's pretty much out of date.